# AMD video driver on 16.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04

Yesterday I made the upgrade to 16.04 and now there are non driver video. Tried to search the web for any answer but nothing. Please can anyone help to have a normal desktop. I don't want to go back to windows. Or there is any way to downgrade back to 15.10 without loosing all my stuff.
This is my VGA:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6620G] [1002:9641]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] [1002:6760]
```

Sorry but I'm not good with computers.

Comment: Please check out the 16.04 release note entry about this change: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes#Graphics_and_Display

Answer (score 2):

The AMD drivers (Catalyst and fglrx) that were available in previous versions of Ubuntu are not available in 16.04 anymore. This is due to bad support from AMD for the Linux drivers. Only the Open-source driver can be used.

I stand to be corrected if some alterative way is known for installing AMD drivers.

The AMD graphics card supported by AMDGPU driver are listad in this link (for Ubuntu 16.04 look at 15.10 column) :https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Comment: Ok thank you fro answer. How can use these drivers? It seems to be no drivers at all. Or at least ho can change the resolution of my desktop and to activate the widescreen option?

Comment: As I said. You can NOT use other driver for AMD graphics in Ubuntu 16.04.  This is the reason I'm not upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04 at the moment. I want to see what experience will others have with this drivers before I change Ubuntu. If your problem is big and the graphics driver is to blame, you should probably downgrade to previous versions. Before doing any upgrade/downgrade -> make backup of all your important data.